# Nested Media Query Performance

Tags: css, sass

I like to nest media queries as a way to keep my code more compartmentalized at the level of a particular selector, so that I don't have to redefine every selector with a media query later in a standalone media query, as one would do in old-school CSS. For example, here's an example media query mixin:

```
@mixin media-query {
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

and here's some example SCSS:

```
.class-1 {
    color: blue;
    @include media-query {
        color: red;
    }
    .class-2 {
        color: blue;
        @include media-query {
            color: red;
        }
        .class-3 {
            color: blue;
            @include media-query {
                color: red;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

However, I found that *not* nesting the media queries like this, and going for a standalone approach, results in a smaller output file when compiled to CSS (and also features only one media query as opposed to many):

```
.class-1 {
    color: blue;
    .class-2 {
        color: blue;
        .class-3 {
            color: blue;
        }   
    }   
}
@include media-query {
    .class-1 {
        color: red;
    }
    .class-2 {
        color: red;
    }
    .class-3 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Is nesting media queries at the selector level a bad practice in SCSS? Is it best to create standalone queries? Also, is the standalone output more performant, because it results in only one actual media query as opposed to many? Thanks in advance for the help, I've read through the sass docs and haven't found anything particularly interesting on this topic.